# Remove local area code on outbound calls, and remove "dial 1" for long distance in Trixbox/Asterisk

Tags: voip, asterisk, freepbx, trixbox

We have Trixbox CE 2.8 and Asterisk 1.6.

I want to remove the 933 area code so you can just dial 555-5555 instead of 933-555-5555 for local calls.

I also want to remove the +1 for long distance so you can dial 555-555-5555 instead of 1-555-555-5555

**FOLLOWUP QUESTION:** What if I want to be able to ***optionally*** dial 1 on a long distance call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the 933 and 1 added the you'd need "Outbound Routes" like this:
NXXXXXX
NXXNXXXXXX

Then, in your Trunks, you want this in the diaplan rules.
933+NXXXXXX
1+NXXNXXXXXX

That would accept NXXXXXX as a valid number from your handsets but would dial 933NXXXXXX when the call goes out on the trunk.  The same goes for the 1.  It will be added to all calls that are dialed with 10 digits.

Comment: I want to add the 933 so that I don't have to dial it every time I make a local call. We only have one area code in this state. Same with the 1.

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: Yes and no. My answer below got it working, but it only works for local 933, not a number across the state. (see above comment)

Comment: I'm having a problem understanding this.  If you want, email me at darren at aleph-com.net and we can work through this and I'll update the answer when it's done.

Comment: I'll just add a comment,we can delete them easily enough. We have one area code, 933. The whole state has this and no other area code. Pretend it's Washington. We are in Seattle, the number for Starbucks is 933-557-5555. We can call 557-5555 and get the call to go to Starbucks in Seattle.

Comment: There is a Best Buy in Spokane, WA that I want to call with the number 933-348-6666. I want to be able to call 348-6666 and be connected without the 933 since the first 3 digits are always going to be 933 in this state. Then, I STILL want to be able to call any 10 digit long distance call and NOT have to dial the 1 first. (as stated in original question) Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was actually this:

Trunk

933|NXXXXXX

1+NXXNXXXXXX

Outbound routes

NXXXNXXXXXX  <--- added adds ability to do +1 or not do +1