# Get Asterisk/Freepbx to ignore digits that were unnecessarily dialed (area code for local calls)

Tags: linux, voip, asterisk, freepbx, trixbox

This is the second part of this question, worded better.

[Remove local area code on outbound calls, and remove "dial 1" for long distance in Trixbox/Asterisk](https://serverfault.com/questions/362794/remove-local-area-code-on-outbound-calls-and-remove-dial-1-for-long-distance/364159#364159)

I have removed the NEED to dial 933 or 1+933 for long distance or local calls already. Additionally, what I want to do is to have Asterisk IGNORE these digits if someone unnecessarily dials them.

So, Joe Dirt calls 1-933-337-0003 when he really could have dialed 337-0003 since it was a local call. Right now, Asterisk is telling him to hang up and try again since this is a local call, and the 1 and/or 933 is not necessary. I want Asterisk to realize Joe Dirt is dumb, and just ignore the extra digits that were dialed and continue his call as though he had only dialed 337-0003.*

*While keeping the existing rules in place.

Answer (score 1):

You need just strip digits.
i.e in freepbx do rule 1933+NXXXXXX in the TRUNK

Comment: OK that got rid of it when dialing 1933-337-0003, but now I cannot dial 933-337-0003 like I could before.

Comment: Here's the trunk right now:

1+NXXNXXXXXX
933|NXXXXXX
1933|NXXXXXX

Still cannot dial 933-337-0003 because it always adds the 1 to the front and then tells me it's not a long distance call. (because it's not) I just need to find a way to add the 1 to all calls EXCEPT ones that start with 933 AND are local. Some 933 calls are not local, these still need the +1.

Comment: you can setup priority and more then 1 rule. so just put your 933 rule before this one.

Comment: I found this guide and am thinking I want to maybe add a line like this somewhere but I'm not quite understanding it yet.

933XXXXXXX

That would stop the +1 from getting added to local calls. But then that would also kill any long distance calls with the 933 because it would lack the +1...

Comment: again, you can add more rules into oubound rule. just press "add more". you can put as many rules as YOU need.